# Mostrar slect caso o select anterior receba valor

Tags: javascript

Pretendo criar um `select` na página do meu login, mas pretendo mostrar a mesma só em caso o `select` anterior receba valor.
Esse `select` que recebe o primeiro valor, já depende de uma `checkbox`, que só é visível caso a `checkbox` seja preenchida, tenho desta forma:

```
<label for="check">Acesso Telemóvel</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" value="1"/>
<label for="hostaname">Indique Qual</label>
<select class="form-control" name="hostaname" id="hostaname" style="display:none">
<option></option>
<option value="ALA A">Telemóvel ALA A</option>
<option value="ALA B">Telemóvel ALA B</option>
<option value="RT + APOIO">Telemóvel RT + APOIO</option>
</select>


$("#check").click(function(){    
   $("#hostaname")[this.checked ? "show" : "hide"]();    
});
```

Agora pretendo criar uma segunda `checkbox` desta forma:

```
<label for="Turno">Indique Qual</label>
<select class="form-control" name="Turno" id="Turno" style="display:none" >
      <option></option>
      <option value="M">Turno Manhã</option>
      <option value="T">Turno tarde</option>
      <option value="N">Turno Noite</option>
</select>
```

Mas que só seja visível caso o `select` anterior for preenchido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vc pode fazer um `if/else` bem simples. Caso no `change` do `select` anterior o `value` seja `==` o `value` que vc quer vc da `display:block` no próximo `select`, `else`, vc da `disply:none` nele.

No exemplo abaixo se o value do `select` anterior for `value == "RT + APOIO"` vc mostra o próximo `select`, se for outro valor vc não mostra nada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
 $("#check").click(function(){    
   $("#hostaname")[this.checked ? "show" : "hide"]();    
});

const sel = document.getElementById('hostaname');

function mostra() {
  const xxx = document.getElementById('Turno');
  if (sel.value == "RT + APOIO") {
      xxx.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      xxx.style.display = "none";
    }
}

sel.addEventListener('change', mostra);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<label for="check">Acesso Telemóvel</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" value="1"/>
<label for="hostaname">Indique Qual</label>
<select class="form-control" name="hostaname" id="hostaname" style="display:none">
<option></option>
<option value="ALA A">Telemóvel ALA A</option>
<option value="ALA B">Telemóvel ALA B</option>
<option value="RT + APOIO">Telemóvel RT + APOIO</option>
</select>


<label for="Turno">Indique Qual</label>
<select class="form-control" name="Turno" id="Turno" style="display:none" >
  <option></option>
  <option value="M">Turno Manhã</option>
  <option value="T">Turno tarde</option>
  <option value="N">Turno Noite</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a mesma abordagem que usou para o checkbox mas dessa vez quando o select mudar de valor. Segue o exemplo:

```js
var myCheckbox$ = $('#myCheckbox');
var fooSelect$ = $('#fooSelect');
var barSelect$ = $('#barSelect');

myCheckbox$.on('click', function(e) {
  fooSelect$[e.target.checked ? 'show' : 'hide']();
});

fooSelect$.on('change', function(e){
  barSelect$[e.target.value ? 'show' : 'hide']();
});
```

```css
#fooSelect, #barSelect {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox"/>
  </label>
  <div>
    <select id="fooSelect">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="foo1">foo1</option>
      <option value="foo2">foo2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <select id="barSelect">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="bar1">bar1</option>
      <option value="bar2">bar2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```